# OpenSecret API only returning text/html

Tags: json, swift, afnetworking

I am attempting to access the open secret API (https://www.opensecrets.org/api) from a swift created iPhone App.

I am using AFNetworking GET request as follows:

```
func getContributors(congressperson: congressPerson!, success: ([NSDictionary]) -> (), failure: (NSError) -> ()){

    let parameters = [
        "cid": congressperson.crpId,
        "output": "json",
        "apikey": opensecretApiKey,
        "cycle": "2016"] as NSDictionary


    GET("api/?method=candContrib", parameters: parameters, progress: nil, success: { (operation: NSURLSessionDataTask, response: AnyObject?) -> Void in

        let results = response!["results"] as! [NSDictionary]
        print("here success")
        success(results)


        }) { (operation: NSURLSessionDataTask?, error: NSError) -> Void in
            print("here fail")
            failure(error)
    }

}
```

Although I am requesting an output of json, this code results in the error:
Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html

Am I doing something wrong in this request?  Anyone know how to force it to return as json?

Comment: If you have the `content-header` set to `application/json` then it all falls back on the server on why you are receiving text/html. It's possible that you are sending the wrong keys, but it sounds like a PHP error. If you post the error you get it will be easier to identify what the problem is.

Comment: How would I set the content-header?  As I understood is should accept json by default.  Is that not true?

Comment: If it helps, when I access the api in a web browser through the same call, it shows up looking like a json file, so it seems to be a problem of AFNetworking not recognizing it as json.